# Have a dApp automatically verify a contract deployed by a factory

Tags: solidity, hardhat, etherscan

Say a contract factory deploys a new contract on Ethereum at any point in time (not when the factory smart contract is deployed). A clone is deployed on trigger by a user.

Is it possible to automatically verify this new contract on Etherscan from the dApp?

PS: I know you can verify it manually on Etherscan, but how if I need the dApp to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Hardhat plugin](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html) that verifies your contract on Etherscan by calling their [verification API](https://docs.etherscan.io/tutorials/verifying-contracts-programmatically).

Comment: The contract is deployed by a factory, not at factory deployment time but at a further point in time, triggered by a user. The hardhat plugin is not helpful here i believe.

Comment: @PmRivière Your Dapp can listen to event logs emitted by the factory contract - e.g. `emit Deployed(instanceAddress);` - and start the verification process as part of handling the event.

Comment: Ok just seeing the "using programmatically" section. Will try this, thanks Petr. https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html#using-programmatically